# Images not loading from URL by Picasso from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, recyclerview-layout

[Firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJu9z.png)

> Model class

```
 public class Category
{
    private String Name;
    private String Image;

    public Category(String name, String image) {
        Name = name;
        Image = image;
    }

    public Category() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

> Activity class

```
 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

        FirebaseDatabase database;
        DatabaseReference reference;
        FirebaseStorage storage;
        StorageReference storageReference;

        //Add new menu
        MaterialEditText edtTxtName;
        Button selectImage;
        Button uploadImage;

        //Adding new category
        Category newCategory;
        Uri savedImageUri;
        private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST=71;
        MaterialEditText edtTxtNewCategoryName;

        FloatingActionButton fab;

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> recyclerAdapter;


        TextView userName;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            edtTxtNewCategoryName=findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_new_item_name);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("Menu Mangement");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            fab =findViewById(R.id.fab);


            //Firebase init
            database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference=database.getReference("Category");
            storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageReference=storage.getReference();

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showDailog();
                }
            });


            DrawerLayout drawer =findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            //Setting header name
          /*  View view=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            userName = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
            userName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());*/
            //View init
            recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
            layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            loadMenu();
        }

        private void selectImage() {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK
            && data!=null && data.getData()!=null)
            {
                savedImageUri=data.getData();//getting uri
                selectImage.setText("Image Selected !");
            }
        }

        private void uploadImage() {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image");
            progressDialog.show();

            String image= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            final StorageReference imageFolder=storageReference.child("images/"+image);
            imageFolder.putFile(savedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
                        {
                            newCategory=new Category(edtTxtName.getText().toString(),uri.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                   double progress=(100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()
                   / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                   progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+progress+" %");

                }
            });
        }

        private void showDailog() {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDailog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDailog.setTitle("Add new Category");
            alertDailog.setMessage("Please fill all the fields");

            LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_menu_layout,null);
            edtTxtName=view.findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_new_item_name);

            alertDailog.setView(view);
            alertDailog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);

            alertDailog.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(newCategory!=null){
                        reference.push().setValue(newCategory);

                    }
                }
            });

            alertDailog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDailog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDailog.show();

        }

        private void loadMenu()
        {
            recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(
                    Category.class,R.layout.menu_layout,
                    MenuViewHolder.class,reference) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, final Category model, int position)
                {
                    viewHolder.menuName.setText(model.getName());
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);

                    viewHolder.setItemClickListner(new ItemClickListner() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                            //Getting menuId
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this,FoodList.class);
                        intent.putExtra("CategoryId",recyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//notifiy us if data has been changed.
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        }
```

***In activity class,firebase adapter is implemented.by refrence of firebase database ,images are loading with only id "-LO061DOhjG2hVZlqY79" but  with id's like '01' '02' are not loading***

**Adapter is loading images very slow**
[Output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLbcE.png)

**Help will highly appreciated**

Comment: show your activity.java class

Comment: Try to log the url with `Log.e("Firebase", "image url = " + model.getImage();` and see what you get.

Comment: in log giving images url fine. but images that are stored in storage are loading but other url images with other link not loading.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. particularly " ...but other url images with other link not loading"?

Comment: 1st image url [image url = https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eatit-444ed.appspot.com/o/images%2F77bb4ee1-57e4-4dad-93fa-038a1a7a7384?alt=media&token=0998fe5a-c912-4f72-a671-9ce404b6e44e]

Comment: but  this isn't loading. (2nd pic url) [image url = http://medifoods.my/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cover-menu-westernsoup1.jpg]

Comment: Actualy this is happening [https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLbcE.png]

Comment: The "2nd pic url"  that doesn't load in your app does not load in a web browser!

Comment: In my second app  same url   is loading properly

Comment: Then the url must be different. As it is listed the url you just provided does not load in a browser, so I can't image how it is being loaded anywhere else. BTW: the first image loads just fine.

Comment: what you suggest now??  please give view in  answer  portion

Comment: I can only suggest that you verify the urls that are in your database and be absolutely certain that the url is correct and reachable by means of a standard http connection.  Bottom line :: VERIFY THE URLs.

Comment: you have to iterate through every child of "Category". then you will get every imageUrl for every child.

Comment: please how can i iterate to each category item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using private fields and public getters and setters, the name of your fields in your `Category` class, doesn't matter. If you want to use different names in your class than in the database, you might use an annotation called [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) in front of the getter.

> images are loading with the only id "-LO061DOhjG2hVZlqY79" but with id's like '01' '02' are not loading

As I see in your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLbcE.png), the image of the first element "01" with the name "Finger Foods" is displayed correctly in the UI. So it doesn't matter if the children have a key that looks like this `01`, `02`, or `-LO061DOhjG2hVZlqY79` the data should be displayed. As a matter of fact, it is displayed, the name of the next item, "Western Soups" is displayed, so most likely the problem is with your URL. So please make sure that the URL actually exists and has it contains a valid image.

Comment: The first part of your answer doesn't make any difference. If there are public getters and setters for a property, the name of the underlying field doesn't matter for the JSON serialization. In fact, it is quite common to name the fields `mName` and `mImage` and that is fine, as long as: 1) the fields are private, 2) the public getter/setter use JavaBean naming convention `getName()`/`setName(String)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yep, some kind of messed up. You're totally right. Just updated my answer. Thank you.