# I am developing an android app with Kotlin and I am trying to get document reference from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android native application with Kotlin and Firebase , I have a collection named Topic and 2 fields of type reference one for User and the other for Category , I was trying to get all documents also with the reference document , but it does not seem to work:

```
db.collection("topic").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {
            Log.e("success", "${document.id} => ${document.data.get("subject")}")
            var topic: Topic = Topic(
                document.id as String,
                document.data.get("subject") as String,
                document.data.get("content") as String,
                document.data.get("created_at") as String,
                document.getDocumentReference("Category") as Category,
                document.getDocumentReference("User") as User
            )}
```

No error , but no result either in my print(topic) .

This is Topic Class

```
class Topic : Serializable {
    var id : String = ""
    var subject : String = ""
    var content : String = ""
    var created_at : String = ""
    var cat = Category()
    var user = User()

    constructor(){}

    constructor(
        id: String,
        subject: String,
        content: String,
        created_at: String,
        cat: Category,
        user: User
    ) {
        this.id = id
        this.subject = subject
        this.content = content
        this.created_at = created_at
        this.cat = cat
        this.user = user
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Topic(id='$id', subject='$subject', content='$content', created_at='$created_at', cat=$cat, user=$user)"
    }
}
```

[image: Database]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your  `Topic` class.

Comment: Hi ,sorry i should have provided that, i added the class and the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get each referenced document explicitly with a separate `get()` call. There's no way to get them automatically in your current call.

So something like:

```
db.collection("topic").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
    for (document in result) {
        document.getDocumentReference("Category").get().addOnSuccessListener { categoryDoc ->
            let category = categoryDoc.data as Category
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Firestore, get the reference document inside another document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128827/firebase-firestore-get-the-reference-document-inside-another-document)
- [What is the use case of reference type in Firestore Document and how to use it specially in an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297645/what-is-the-use-case-of-reference-type-in-firestore-document-and-how-to-use-it-s)

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen for your response and especially your code that explains what i should do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
document.getDocumentReference("Category") as Category
```

You are getting an object of type `DocumentReference` and **not** an object of type `Category` because DocumentSnapshot's [getDocumentReference()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getDocumentReference(java.lang.String)) method returns that kind of object. Remember that in Kotlin, there is no way you can cast an object of type `DocumentReference` to `Category`, hence that behaviour.

So the assumption that simply getting a reference to an object will return the object itself is **not** correct. The only way in which you can solve this is to make separate calls for each one of them, as @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his answer.

As a separate topic, you can also take a look at my answer from the below post, as I saw that you are using different naming for the properties in the document:

- [First letter of variable's name is changing from uppercase to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403797/first-letter-of-variables-name-is-changing-from-uppercase-to-lowercase)

Comment: I thank you for your answer @Alex Mamo, it helped me understand the concept of the DocumentReference .

Comment: You're very welcome CHARFEDDINE! My anwer it's an addition to what @FrankvanPuffelen answered.