# Reading and writing to firebase database using Firebase list adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from the Firebase database in a `ListView`. Each item in the `ListView` comes with a button, once that button is clicked the read data set in the textviews are written to the databse. The code below is the code I used for both showing the `ListView` and writing to the database.[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpDxt.png)

```
 if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ==null{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"logon first", Toast. Length.SHORT).show() ; 
   } else{
    display() ;
    } 

 private void display(){
    Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("border_details");
    FirebaseListOptions<DRive>options=new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<DRive>().setQuery(query,DRive.class).setLayout(R.layout.messages).build();
    ListView list= findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
    adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<DRive>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, DRive model, int position) {
            Button d=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_accept);
            final TextView z=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
            final TextView c=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pickup);
            final TextView f=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timed);
            final TextView m=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.points);
            z.setText(model.getDropoffspot());
            c.setText(model.getPickupspot());
            f.setText(model.getPickuptime());
            m.setText(model.getKey());
            d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DRive dRive=new DRive();
                    hec();
                    dRive.setDropoffspot(chi);
                    dRive.setKey(pt);
                    dRive.setPickupspot(g);
                    dRive.setPickuptime(boo);
                    dRive.setKey(pt);
                    myRef.child(pt).push().setValue(dRive);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"shi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                private void hec() {
                    pt=m.getText().toString();
                    boo=f.getText().toString();
                    chi=z.getText().toString();
                    g=c.getText().toString();
                }
            });




        }
    };
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is my json

```
{
"order_details" : {
"DEzUoNY6BqOVn1DVIbFwOk6B4dT2" : {
  "-LlkSlkLOZYY7iy5vBWY" : {
    "dropoffspot" : "17 nursery crescent",
    "key" : "DEzUoNY6BqOVn1DVIbFwOk6B4dT2",
    "kutaPoints" : 80,
    "pickupspot" : "Mukuba l",
    "pickuptime" : "teaTime"
  }
}
```

}
}

this is my drive class

```
public class DRive {
private String Pickuptime;
private String Pickupspot;
private String Dropoffspot;
private String passengers;
private String Key;
public DRive(String passengers, String Pickupspot, String Pickuptime, String Dropoffspot, String Key){
    this.Dropoffspot=Dropoffspot;
    this.Pickupspot=Pickupspot;
    this.passengers=passengers;
    this.Pickuptime=Pickuptime;
    //mestime=new Date().getTime();

}
public DRive(){

}
public String getPickuptime(){
    return Pickuptime;
}

public void setPickuptime(String time) {
    this.Pickuptime = time;
}

public String getDropoffspot() {
    return Dropoffspot;
}

public void setDropoffspot(String dropoffspot) {
    this.Dropoffspot = Dropoffspot;
}

public String getPickupspot() {
    return Pickupspot;
}

public void setPickupspot(String pickupspot) {
    this.Pickupspot = Pickupspot;
}

public String getPassengers() {
    return passengers;
}

public String getKey() {
    return Key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    Key = key;
}
```

The app is supposed to read data from the child `order_details` and display that in the `ListView` using the `FirebaseListAdapter`, instead the app does not.

The app is supposed to read from the database and display the retrieved data in the parts of the listview using the `FirebaseListAdapter`, instead it does not even show the `ListView`. Kindly render assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix my issue. I added an onstart and onstop listener like shown below

```
  @Override 
   protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
   }
   @Override 
    protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         adapter.stopListening();
   }
  }
```

I also made adjustments to my Textview code by adding 'v' after introducing a textview, for example. 
Instead of 
           final TextView f=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timed);
I changed it to 
         final TextView f=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.timed);

Answer (score 0):

Between your `order_details` node and the actual `DRive` objects there is another child. As I see in your database is the `uid` of the authenticated user. In order to solve this issue, you need to add a call to that child too. So please change the following line of code:

```
Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("order_details");
```

to

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("order_details").child(uid);
```

**Edit:**

There is no way using your actual database structure to query the database and get all orders of all users in a single go. If you want that, you should reconsider your database structure or simply duplicate data. If you want to get all orders of all users, please see a possible schema below:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- order_details
        |
        --- orderIdOne
        |     |
        |     --- //orderDetails
        |     |
        |     --- uid: "DEzUoNY6BqOVn1DVIbFwOk6B4dT2"
        |
        --- orderIdTwo
              |
              --- //orderDetails
              |
              --- uid: "USw0LFY6BqOVn1DVIbFwOkhcvPwf"
```

To get all orders simply attach a listener on `order_details` node and if you want to get all orders that corresponde to a single user, please use the following query:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference orderDetailsRef = rootRef.child("order_details");
Query query = orderDetailsRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

**Edit2:**

You arent't getting anything due the fact that the fields in your `DRive` class do not match the one in the database. To solve this, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Images not loading from URL by Picasso from Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670456/images-not-loading-from-url-by-picasso-from-firebase-database/52706350#52706350)

Comment: The thing is, that is only the writing of one user in the json file, once other users access the app they will write data in the same way that I did, and I want all that data to be accessible in the list view. There will be different user id's in the same order_details node

Comment: Fair enough, but you still need to add the call to `.child(uid)`. Have you tried it, does it work?

Comment: I haven't, but won't it only return data for the current user? Ideally the user is supposed to view evern other users data

Comment: So you should try it. In the meanwhile, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this first thing in the morning, I really appreciate it, it makes so much sense, am sure it will work

Comment: Ok, keep me posted with your progress.

Comment: The list view is still not showing any content, and I did make the changes to the database you suggested

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the earlier part of my code? Let me show the top part where the display method is used

Comment: Show me now your new database strucutre, as a screenshot please and add the code that you are using to get the data.

Comment: Okay let me edit the question to include the screenshot and the code to get the data

Comment: Please also add the content of  your `DRive` class.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: I see now where the problem is. So pelase see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: It has still failed, nothing is showing. I tried both methods

Comment: Saying "It has still failed" doesn't help me help you Please provide more info and show me again, your database schema, the content of your `DRive` class and the code that you are using.

Comment: My apologies. for the code I am using, I am still using the same code as shown in the question, however I changed the DRive class according to the way your previous post advised. I will update it right away. Perhaps though there is something wrong with my xml files, could that be the case? I have also not made any changes to the database

Comment: Show me your the new changes. Have you only changed your `DRive` class or also in the database?