# Why I can't use the whereEqualTo condition in query Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I want to do is check first if The referral code inserted by the user exist. But the problem is, it is always going on the addOnSuccessListener even though I had entered text which are not included in the database.

//Dont mind the next paragraph. I just need to add some more descriptions to save the edit//

What I want to do is check first if The referral code inserted by the user exist. But the problem is, it is always going on the addOnSuccessListener even though I had entered text which are not included in the database.

What I want to do is check first if The referral code inserted by the user exist. But the problem is, it is always going on the addOnSuccessListener even though i had entered text which are not included in the database.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("Buyers");
Query usersDataQuery = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("referrals.userReferralCOde", referalCode);
                usersDataQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Users users = new Users();
                        String referedByID = users.getBuyerID();

                        loadingBar = KProgressHUD.create(FirstTimeUserActivity.this)
                                .setStyle(KProgressHUD.Style.SPIN_INDETERMINATE)
                                .setLabel("Please wait")
                                .setDetailsLabel("Creating your Account...")
                                .show();
                        //withReferrals(cfn, cln, referedByID, email, status, id);
                        StyleableToast.makeText(FirstTimeUserActivity.this, "Pumasok.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.successtoast).show();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        StyleableToast.makeText(FirstTimeUserActivity.this, "Please enter a Valid Referral Code.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.errortoast).show();

                    }
```

```
public class Users {
    private String BuyerID, Email, FirstName, LastName, ImageUrl, AccountType, CPoints, WalletAccount;
    private double Latitude, Longitude;
    private @ServerTimestamp Date timestamp;
    private ReferralModel Referrals;

    public Users(){

    }

    public Users(String buyerID, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String imageUrl, String accountType, String CPoints, String walletAccount, double latitude, double longitude, Date timestamp, ReferralModel referrals) {
        BuyerID = buyerID;
        Email = email;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        AccountType = accountType;
        this.CPoints = CPoints;
        WalletAccount = walletAccount;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        Referrals = referrals;
    }

  public String getBuyerID() {
        return BuyerID;
    }

    public void setBuyerID(String buyerID) {
        BuyerID = buyerID;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return ImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getAccountType() {
        return AccountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        AccountType = accountType;
    }

    public String getCPoints() {
        return CPoints;
    }

    public void setCPoints(String CPoints) {
        this.CPoints = CPoints;
    }

    public String getWalletAccount() {
        return WalletAccount;
    }

    public void setWalletAccount(String walletAccount) {
        WalletAccount = walletAccount;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public ReferralModel getReferrals() {
        return Referrals;
    }

    public void setReferrals(ReferralModel referrals) {
        Referrals = referrals;
    }

                });[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr9Vm.png
```

Comment: Change `referrals.userReferralCOde` to `referrals.userReferralCode`.

Comment: Thank for replying sir Alex Mamo But it is still the same. It is still going to the onSuccessListener.

Comment: Please also add the content of your  `Users` class.

Comment: Okay please wait.

Comment: sir I had updated the question. Please take a look if that helps you find my error. Thank you!

Comment: I will write you an answer right away.

Comment: Okay thank you sir!

Comment: Check my below answer and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the fact that you have a typo in your code `referrals.userReferralCOde` as is should be `referrals.userReferralCode`, you aren't getting any `Users` object from the database because you are creating a new one. You can simply use `addOnCompleteListener` and you'll see that the `QuerySnapshot` object contains data that is coming from the database. To see the results, you should iterate, like in the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference buyersReference = rootRef.collection("Buyers");
Query usersDataQuery = buyersReference.whereEqualTo("referrals.userReferralCode", "123");
usersDataQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String firstName = document.getString("firstName");
                Log.d(TAG, firstName);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result in your logcat will be all users that have `userReferralCode` equal to `123`. Please also note that fields in your class do **not** coresponde with the one from the database. For that, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Images not loading from URL by Picasso from Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670456/images-not-loading-from-url-by-picasso-from-firebase-database/52706350#52706350)

So if yo want to get data as an object of `Users` class, use the recommendations from that answer.

Comment: Sir this helps me a lot. Can I ask if how will I use my Users.class to get the buyersID? Thank you so much!

Comment: You'll be able to use `Users users = document.toObject(Users.class)` only after you solve the issue regarding the naming of your properties.