# App keeps stopping whenever I open RecyclerView activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

My app keeps stopping unexpectedly whenever I try to open the activity with recycler view. I have tried many other ways to add recycler view in my activity.but none of them work. Other activities work flawlessly.

Firestore is sending data to my app, Data Reads count increases every time I run activity with recycler view.

What am I doing wrong?

my logcat error

```
2020-08-13 15:50:12.895 17761-17761/? E/om.example.rus: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-08-13 15:50:20.355 17761-17761/com.example.rush E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rush, PID: 17761
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: name
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.addProperty(CustomClassMapper.java:736)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(CustomClassMapper.java:640)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:377)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:540)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:100)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:187)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:116)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:165)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:97)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:23)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:12)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:86)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:158)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
2020-08-13 15:50:20.356 17761-17761/com.example.rush E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

MainActivity

```
   package com.example.rush;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference NameRef = db.collection("TalesSR");
    private TalesAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        setUpRecyclerView();

    }
    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = NameRef.orderBy("Name", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<TalesDetails> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<TalesDetails>()
                .setQuery(query, TalesDetails.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new TalesAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Model Class

```
public class TalesDetails {

    public TalesDetails(String name) {
        Name = name;
       
    }

    public String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public TalesDetails() {}


   

}
```

Adapter Class

```
package com.example.rush;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

public class TalesAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<TalesDetails, TalesAdapter.TalesHolder> {

    public TalesAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<TalesDetails> options) {

        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TalesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull TalesDetails talesDetails) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(talesDetails.getName());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TalesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewtales,
                parent, false);
        return new TalesHolder(v);

    }

    class TalesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;


        public TalesHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        }
    }
}
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank You so much.I have been stuck on this for the past 2 days

Comment: You're very welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you are having in your `TalesDetails` class, the `name` property set as public, and with an incorrect name. If you want to use public fields, then there is no need for adding getters or setters, otherwise, make it private as below:

```
public class TalesDetails {
    private String name; //Is set private and starting with a lowercase

    public TalesDetails() {}

    public TalesDetails(String name) {
        name = name; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }
}
```

See, the `name` property now is starting with a lowercase. Besides that, be careful to have the name set with lowercase as well in the database.

You might also check the following three answers, [lowercase letter in class, capital in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670456/images-not-loading-from-url-by-picasso-from-firebase-database/52706350#52706350), [capital letter in class, lowercase in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924189/how-to-read-firestore-sub-collection-and-pass-it-to-firestorerecycleroptions/53943559#53943559) and [capital letter in class, capital in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069574/firebase-android-listview-not-being-displayed).